# Creating sublists based on the first column

Tags: list-manipulation

I have Excel file consisting of two columns such as:

```
1.2.2014 23:35  |-0.007378

1.2.2014 23:40  |-0.004121

1.2.2014 23:45  |-0.000122

1.2.2014 23:50  |0.000117

1.2.2014 23:55  |-0.000542
```

When I import that in Mathematica, it creates list like:

List={{1.2.2014 23:35, -0.007378}, {1.2.2014 23:40, -0.004121}, ..., {2.2.2014 00:00, -0.004897}, {2.2.2014 00:05, -0.005179}, ...}

And I need to create a list where only the values from the second column will be and these values will create sublists based on the day of observations. So it should look like (based on "List" above):

List2={{-0.007378, -0.004121, ...}, {-0.004897, -0.005179, ...}, ...}.

The question may be very similar to this one:
[Split dataset based on the first column](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28977/split-dataset-based-on-the-first-column)
...but I cannot figure out how the mentioned method should be applied in my case, where I have dates in the first column.

Thanks for any help. And sorry if it is an easy problem, but I am still begginer with Mathematica.

Comment: Johny, please include the *exact* expression returned by `Import`, or at least a truncated version of it. Some or all of the data is probably in `String` form, though this is not shown in your current excerpt.  This will change how the data is handled.

Comment: try `list=Import[(*your file*)];` `Partition[list[[All,2]],2]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting with:

```
data = Import["btc.xlsx"] // First;
```

your time stamps are being imported in the [`DateObject`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DateObject.html) format:

```
data[[1, 1]] // InputForm
```

> DateObject[{2011, 12, 31}, TimeObject[{0, 5, 0.}]]

The first argument is a Y/M/D triplet that we can [`Extract`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Extract.html) for use in [`GatherBy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GatherBy.html) or [`GroupBy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GroupBy.html):

```
GatherBy[data, Extract[{1, 1}]][[All, All, 2]]
```

Or:

```
GroupBy[data, Extract[{1, 1}] -> Last] // Values
```

The [operator form](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/56504/121) of `Extract` is used in each example.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood rightly, a starting point could be:

```
dateString[date_] := DateString[date, {"Year", "Month", "Day"}];
dString[arg_] := dateString[First[arg]];
dataOut = Gather[dataIn, (dString[#1] == dString[#2]) &];
```

If you wish, you can provide us a plain text file version of your data (es. Dropbox ...)  and I will try to help further.

Comment: Please forgive, for security reasons, I can't open a xlsx file on this machine. Can you save data as plain txt (xml, csv, html ...) and zip it ? I would be pleased to help, this way.

Answer (score 1):

```
list= {{"1.2.2014 23:35  ", -0.007378`}, {"1.3.2014 23:40  ", -0.004121`},
       {"1.2.2014 23:45  ", -0.000122`}, {"1.3.2014 23:50  ",  0.000117`}, 
       {"1.2.2014 23:55  ", -0.000542`}};

list2 = {DateList[{StringTrim@#, 
         {"Month", "Day", "Year", "Hour", "Minute"}}][[;; 3]], #2} & @@@ list;

Values@GroupBy[ First -> Last][list2]
(* or Values@GroupBy[list2, First -> Last] *)
(* {{-0.007378,-0.000122,-0.000542},{-0.004121,0.000117}} *)
```

Comment: @Johny, with the data you posted, you don't need to  process the first column to get datelists. With `list=Import[...]`,  you can try `Last/@#&/@(Values@GroupBy[ #[[1,;;3]] &][list])`.